# how to get a d3.js graph's value at a particular point?

Tags: d3.js

I've got a group of graphs (using angular 7 and d3.js v5).
with axis x=> date , y values, it's a curve (basis).
I'd like to be able to enter a date and display at this particular date the value. My problem is , i do not see how to retreive the calculated values for a given date.
Is it possible? 
I did not find anything.

I add an image to clarify.
[image]

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a simple answer that'd work in general case.

In your case however, since you are using basis curve, and your data is in equal intervals, you can use d3 basis interpolator https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate#interpolateBasis

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
    }
    
    rect {
      fill: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var points = [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      {
        x: 5,
        y: 10
      },
      {
        x: 10,
        y: 20
      },
      {
        x: 15,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 20,
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: 25,
        y: 10
      },
      {
        x: 30,
        y: 12
      },
      {
        x: 35,
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: 40,
        y: 20
      },
    ];

    var interp = d3.interpolateBasis(points.map(function(p) {
      return p.y;
    }));
    var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 40])
      .range([0, 200]);
    var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([-10, 30])
      .range([200, 0]);
    var lineGen = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return scaleX(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return scaleY(d.y);
      })
      .curve(d3.curveBasis);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);

    svg.append('rect')
      .attr('width', 200)
      .attr('height', 200)
      .on('mousemove', function() {
        var x = d3.event.x;
        var y = interp(x / scaleX(40));
        svg.select('circle')
          .attr('cx', x)
          .attr('cy', scaleY(y));
        svg.select('text')
          .text('x: ' + scaleX.invert(x) + ', y: ' + y);
      })

    svg.append('path')
      .attr('d', lineGen(points));

    svg.append('text')
      .attr('y', 20);

    svg.append('circle')
      .attr('r', 3);
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a bisector, and d3 has built-in functionality for it. You can create a bisect function like this:

`const bisectDate = d3.bisector(d=>d.date).right;`

Then use it with an inverse of a given x position. Here's the d3 documentation on its bisect methods:

https://github.com/d3/d3-array#bisectLeft

And d3 documentation on inverting scales:

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_invert

And a working example of a line chart that bisects the mouse x position to get the value at a given date:

https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/cfb7dcd7951826b9eacd54f0647f48d3

Comment: 1) OP uses curves, not straight lines. And not just simple curves at that, but a type that doesn't even necessarily go through it's data / control point

Comment: 2) OP asks about finding interpolated value in between data points, and not just simply extracting the closest point to mouse from data array

Comment: OP asks how to find interpolated value between 2 points, and yet your answer only shows how get value for closest point. If you look closer to the picture, it shows values at 05/15 and 07/15 are *given*, and value of 06/15 is not part of the data, thus he wants to find it's interpolated value

Comment: and you cannot trivially just interpolate between 2 points for b-spline, you need to take surrounding points though I'm not sure how much at minimum. In my answer I take all of the points because it's simpler that way, and you also only need to calculate it once